# C++ no instance of overloaded function matches the argument list E0304

Tags: c++

https://youtu.be/oD1dvfbyf6A?si=8c7aTRyGrFJQRPFR

I'm following this YouTube series on OpenGL, and at around the 13:00 mark, my code throws this error on the `push_back` function. No matter what I try, I can't figure out what is different between my code and his.

```
Error (active)  E0304   no instance of overloaded function "std::vector<_Ty, _Alloc>::push_back [with _Ty=VertexBufferElement, _Alloc=std::allocator<VertexBufferElement>]" matches the argument list   TheChernoOpenGl C:\Users\Hunter Martenson\source\repos\TheChernoOpenGl\TheChernoOpenGl\src\VertexBufferLayout.h 31
```

```cpp
#pragma once

#include <vector>
#include <GL/glew.h>

struct VertexBufferElement
{
    unsigned int type;
    unsigned int count;
    bool normalized;
};

class VertexBufferLayout
{
private:
    std::vector<VertexBufferElement> m_Elements;
    unsigned int m_Stride;
public:
    VertexBufferLayout ()
    : m_Stride(0) {}

    template<typename T>
    void Push (int count)
    {
        static_assert(false);
    }

    template<>
    void Push<float> (int count)
    {
        m_Elements.push_back({ GL_FLOAT, count, false });
        m_Stride += sizeof(GLfloat);
    }

    template<>
    void Push<unsigned int> (int count)
    {
        m_Elements.push_back ({GL_UNSIGNED_INT, count, false });
        m_Stride += sizeof (GLuint);
    }

    template<>
    void Push<unsigned char> (int count)
    {
        m_Elements.push_back ({GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, count, true });
        m_Stride += sizeof (GLbyte);
    }

    inline const std::vector<VertexBufferElement> GetElements () const { return m_Elements; }
    inline unsigned int GetStride () const { return m_Stride; }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried using `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`? For example: `m_Elements.emplace_back(GL_FLOAT, count, false);`

Comment: For one, `count` is `int` but your struct has an `unsigned int` field.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone in the future with the same issue I managed to fix my error by changing this code.

```
struct VertexBufferElement
{
    unsigned int count;
    unsigned int type;
    bool normalized;

    VertexBufferElement (unsigned int t, unsigned int c, bool n) :
        type (t), count (c), normalized (n)
    {

    }
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).